# Windows NLA issue at co-location (site-to-site VPN): several machines cannot recognize network, domain is "unauthenticated"

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

Our corporate office is here in The States. We host a modest data center that has our DC's, Exchange, SQL, etc (all Windows shop here). Our second biggest office is in London and connected via site-to-site VPN (two Cisco ASA's). Recently we have been getting flooded with help desk tickets that read as follows:
**"I have rebooted cannot connect to the corp wired (and/or corp wireless) network/s. I *can* use Guest Wi-Fi, however."**

When remoting to a machine, we will see the LAN connection identified as either "OurDomain.local (Unauthenticated)" *or* "BT-Hub5" or similar. Troubleshooting this extensively, we have found symptomatic fixes as it is a NLA (**network location awareness**) issue:

1. 1a. Dis-join and rejoin domain, reboot - this is if one of the two
   connections (wired/wireless) is still working with the domain.
   1b. *Or* if neither wired or wireless are working with the domain, connect software client VPN (Cisco AnyConnect), run PowerShell with
   Domain Admin creds: `Reset-ComputerMachinePassword -Server OurDC1`
   then reboot.

   2. Completely uninstall and reinstall the NIC drivers.
   3. Run these two CMD's: `netsh reset winsock` && `netsh int IP reset` then reboot.
   4. RegEdit.exe -> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\` -> Find and delete all
      faulty/duplicate network profiles, reboot.
   5. (Optional step?) Disable IPv6 on both wired and wireless NIC's. Our DC's do not use IPv6 (thanks to our IT director - don't get me
      started).

So, my question is: **What could be the network issue causing this? How can I identify and fix it?**

DC's are all Windows Server 2012 R2. Clients are a mix of Win7 & Win10, all Dell laptops (if it matters).

EDIT: Could a **rouge DHCP server** cause this? And/or **double NAT'ing**?

Comment: How is this related to network level authentication? NLA is for authenticating remote desktop sessions. Perhaps you mean network location awareness?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I meant Network Level Awareness. I will update the post.

Comment: Let's try again. It's called **Network Location Awareness**. What do these machines show as their active network profile in Network and Sharing Center?

Comment: @joeqwerty, work profile.

Comment: does this happen on both the windows 7 and 10 clients?

Comment: @JimB, yes, both Win10 and Win7 clients have the issue.

Comment: A couple of things; I know you can't do anything about it, but disabling IPv6 is something that people who don't know what they're doing do. My question to you is what are the affected clients using for DNS? Hopefully they're only using your AD DNS servers.

Comment: I get that, and disabling IPv6 didn't help anyhow. All clients are using our AD servers for DNS, yes. However, the DNS servers are here in the States (not in London) so connect over the StS VPN. When this issue occurs the clients _do_ get an IP but they cannot route out of the LAN and DNS does not work. So, only layer 2 works when this issue is occurring. No DNS, no route in or out of the LAN.

Comment: So, apparently the Cisco ASA was just under-licensed for the number of active connections during peak hours.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly being caused by your machines inconsistently being able to determine Network Location, and therefore enforcing different Windows Firewall profiles, and maybe different VPN settings, depending on your environment.

This is more of an architecture problem than a network problem. You shouldn't be expecting Active Directory and associated services like NLA to work behind even one NAT, let alone two.

Network Location Awareness does its first checks by checking for connectivity to the last contacted domain controller. Note that you can override some of the NLA checks by using Group Policy to determine location via the ability to resolve a DNS name, or the ability to connect to an HTTP endpoint only accessible from the corporate LAN, but you'd be better served by addressing the root cause -- your machines can't contact a domain controller, and therefore don't function as if they were in a corporate network.

What you need to do is to look at your architecture -- why not have a read-only domain controller at the remote site? That would be a secure way for remote clients to determine that they were in fact connected to the corporate network.

Comment: Good info, thank you vella! I agree with your assessment of the issue, but I still don't know what _exactly_ has caused this change. I would love to put a RODC in that office, but am extremely doubtful our IT Director would approve it. He is very conservative and see's everything as "well it was working before.." SMH

Comment: DNS was not setup correctly as this site: the secondary DNS server is a BT (British Telecom) nameserver, **not** our DC2 like it should be! I'm all but certain that this is the root of our issue - the VPN has been dropping more than it should, causing the connection to DC1 to fail, so local (Active Directory DNS) fails. BT nameserver is fine for the internet, but breaks AD sync from the remote site to our corp network here.

Comment: Sorry to take away the answer credit, but this wasn't exactly the case in our scenario. Still very helpful info though, so thank you!